# How to get the file from the directory using command line arguments using perl?

Tags: perl

---

I tried to fetch the file with folder name(i.e pro) and location(i.e “/c/lol/ap/a/ds/crent/stup/pjects/DEMO/mfile.txt)  and run the script(i.e perl readfile.pl) using command line arguments.So i tried for the following sample script by my own.But i feel my script is totally wrong.Could anyone help me the right way to approach.

Sample Script:(perl readfile.pl)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
my $pro;
my $mfile;
my $odir;
GetOptions('pro' => \$pro) or die "Usage: $0 --pro\n";
GetOptions('mfile' =>\$mfile) or die "Usage:$0 --mfile\n";
GetOptions('odir' =>\$odir) or die "Usage:$0 --odir\n";
print $pro ? 'pro' : 'no pro';
```

Error:

```
Unknown option: mfile
Unknown option: odir
Usage: readfile.pl --pro
```

To run command line as follows :

I should create the script to run the command line as follows.

```
perl readfile.pl -pro “pr1” -mfile “/c/lol/ap/a/ds/crent/stup/pjects/DEMO/mfile.txt” -odir “/home/html_files”
```

Comment: What is the objective of the script? To print the contents of a file passed via arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `GetOptions('pro' => \$pro)` sees all options other than `-pro` as invalid, so you must process all possible command line options in a single call

Since your options have a string value, you also need to append `=s` to the option name

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Getopt::Long 'GetOptions';

GetOptions(
    'pro=s'   => \my $pro,
    'mfile=s' => \my $mfile,
    'odir=s'  => \my $odir,
);

print $pro   ? "pro   = $pro\n"   : "no pro\n";
print $mfile ? "mfile = $mfile\n" : "no mfile\n";
print $odir  ? "odir  = $odir\n"  : "no odir\n";
```

#### output

```
pro   = pr1
mfile = /c/lol/ap/a/ds/crent/stup/pjects/DEMO/mfile.txt
odir  = /home/html_files
```

Comment: It helps my query.Great explanation@Borodin

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but your usage of `GetOptions` is wrong. If you call it, this tries to process *all* commandline options, not just one. So everything not defined in your first call to `GetOption` ends up triggering the `or die ...` part at the end and stops the program, resulting in the usage message. Please look up [PerlDoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) for some useful examples.

You also have to use two hyphens for your options in the commandline call to let it work...

Comment: *"You also have to use two hyphens for your options in the commandline call to let it work"* No, you don't.